# Did the Romans abbreviate the days of the week?

Tags: classical-latin, roman-culture, abbreviations

In current Spanish when we have to abbreviate the days of the week using only one character, in most places (but not everywhere) to tell apart *martes* (Tuesday) from *miércoles* (Wednesday) we use 'M' and 'X', respectively.

I have read several stories about the origin of the 'X' abbreviation. One of them states that as *miércoles* originates from *[dies] [Mercurii](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=mercurius&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)*, and as this word comes from *[merx](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=merx&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)*, we can tell apart *Mars* (that originated *martes*) from *merx* using the last 'X'.

But if this story is true, this abbreviation could have been used already in the times of the Roman Empire. So my question is: how did the Romans abbreviate the names of the days of the week? Did them by any chance use the X for *dies Mercurii* to tell it apart from *dies Martis*?

Comment: Good question! Perhaps before answering this one has to describe how (if at all!) the days of the week were used in antiquity. My impression is that they are a later addition to the calendar system. It might make sense to ask a prequel question.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta [better done that said](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11042/2646). :-)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: the seven-day planetary week is first alluded to by Tibullus (1st century BC).

Comment: @fdb Would it be possible to write up an answer about the relevant passage from Tibullus to [the other question about the days of the week](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11042/79)?

Comment: Fun fact: in Chile it is not uncommon to abbreviate _miércoles_ as **W** (for Wednesday): DLMWJVSD